# Using SQL's CONVERT(binary, ?) with Laravel's whereRaw

Tags: sql-server, laravel, binary, type-conversion, sqlsrv

I am using [Laravel's raw query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions) to connect and retrieve records from a SQL Server.

```
$rfaccounts = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('tbl_rfaccount')
            ->whereRaw("id = CONVERT(binary, 'acc1')")
            ->get();
```

That works and successfully returns the database record but it's dangerous because I need to replace "acc1" with a submitted form field so it becomes susceptible to SQL injection.

```
$rfaccounts = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('tbl_rfaccount')
            ->whereRaw("id = CONVERT(binary, '?')", 'acc1')
            ->get();
```

But this doesn't work... and removing the ' ' from '?' SQL just throws an error saying that it can't find column "acc1".

So how do I go about doing this?

Comment: You have to remove the quotes: `->whereRaw("id = CONVERT(binary, ?)", 'acc1')`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir If I remove the quotes SQL just throws an error saying that it can't find column acc1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do it the other way around.

```
$rfaccounts = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('tbl_rfaccount')
            ->whereRaw("CONVERT(varchar, id) = ?", 'acc1')
            ->get();
```

Still don't know why it didn't work.